# Convert C++ enum to python int

Tags: c++, python

I have a python wrapper for a C++ function that returns an enum.

When I do the following:

returnValue = mylibrary_py.getRole() # this returns an enum

I get the following error when I load my web page:

```
No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: mynamespace::MyRole
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: From the error message, I'm guessing you're using Boost.Python. If so, [here's](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/enum.html) how you expose an enum to Python. If that doesn't fix your problem, then please post more code showing the enum definition and how you're wrapping your code.

Answer (score 0):

How is the Python wrapper generated?  Enum's convert implicitly to `int` (and to other integral types), so the Python wrapper must be doing something special to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Find the way how to expose enum type to python at following:
[Enums from C++ to Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/enum.html)